# how i can use async function in discord js to make a question game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, discord, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot that will ask me a question if I type done in a specific time it should say nice u won if its the answer but if it reached 7 second it should say time up but I don't know sometimes it spams the channel by time up how i can fix please I'm stuck there for 8 hours?

```
/* === countries image === */

var   kurdistan = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Flag_of_Kurdistan.svg/800px-Flag_of_Kurdistan.svg.png";
var   catalonia = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Catalonia.svg/810px-Flag_of_Catalonia.svg.png";
var   palastine = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Flag_of_Palestine.svg/800px-Flag_of_Palestine.svg.png";


/* === countries names === */

const obj = [
 kurdistan,
 catalonia,
 palastine
];

/* === code === */



client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
  
          const ranImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * obj.length); 
          if(message.content === 'flag') {
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
             embed.setTitle('Flag guesser');
             embed.setDescription('which countries flag does this belong?');
             embed.setImage(obj[ranImg]);
             embed.setColor(0x3aeb34);
             embed.setFooter('this game provided by by me');
             embed.setTimestamp();
             message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
              let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
  
              message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: '7000', errors: ['time'] })
               .then(collected => {  
//when it gives me the image and I write the correct answer of the obj[ranImg] it doesn't says you win all the time it says try again  
                  if (collected.first().content === obj[ranImg]) {
                    return message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: You win!') //they won 
                  } else {
                    return message.channel.send(`:x: Oooh close! Try again!`); // they lost 
                  }
               })
               .catch(collected => {
                  return message.channel.send('times up! no answers were collected!');
               });
            });
        }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message collectors are difficult, and you are really close. You don't need to define the awaitMessages, and also, await is already async so you don't need to type `async` before the `#awaitMessages`. Also, you need a `#then` to lead onto the `#awaitMessages`.

Also, collectors have a concept of `#catch` systems if an error is thrown defined by the `errors: ['time']` obj.

`maxMatches` is outdated, it was changed in v12 to `max`

To conclude, I will combine all of the above to fix your code:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return; //have this here so the command does as little as possible before returning

        const ranImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * obj.length); 
        if(message.content === 'flag') {
           const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
           embed.setTitle('Flag guesser');
           embed.setDescription('which countries flag does this belong?');
           embed.setImage(obj[ranImg]);
           embed.setColor(0x3aeb34);
           embed.setFooter('this game provided by by me');
           embed.setTimestamp();
           message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
            let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: '7000', errors: ['time'] })
             .then(collected => {
                if (collected.first().content === obj[ranImg]) {
                  return message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: You win!') //they won 
                } else {
                  return message.channel.send(`:x: Oooh close! Try again!`); // they lost 
                }
             })
             .catch(collected => {
                return message.channel.send('times up! no answers were collected!'); // if the timer of 7000ms elapses, catch here
             });
          });
      }
  }
);
```

[Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) is a guide if you still need more help

Comment: oh thanks it worked for me and I learnt a lot all the thanks to you but I have one more problem which is the ran[obj] doesn't give me the correct answer so its all the time wrong answer my objects and variables up that provide me the random image is /* /* === countries image === */
```
var   kurdistan =  // link of kurdistan
var   palastine = // link of palastine
var Catalonia = // link of catalonia
/* === countries names === */

const obj = [
 kurdistan,
 catalonia,
 Palestine
];
*/
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, and as for your problem I have no idea what you mean, you will have to explain in greater detail

Comment: i did it , i meant when I get random image that I should guess when i write the correct answer like the object key i don't get the message which says you win as u see in
```
   if (collected.first().content === obj[ranImg]) // the random object 
```

Comment: I dont know where obj is defined so you would have to update your code above to explain properly

Comment: i did, please take  a look at the comment I added after .then(collected)